# LoginView not display databound control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've come to a scenario where I need to databind something only if the user is logged in. To do this I am using the LoginView control to display a Login control when they are not logged in and a GridView control when they are logged in. However, when I databind to the GridView object in the LoginView, nothing ever gets displayed. I have been debugging it and I am databinding it to a DataTable that definitely has data in it, however nothing shows up.

Here is some of the code:
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1")).DataSource = dt;
            ((GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1")).DataBind();
        }

Is there a particular reason that this should not work? Is it bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you use **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** when your GridView is in the **LoginView Control**? Both things do sort of the same. I think you have a race-condition here.

Use the LoginViewControl in your ASPX-page *OR* the if/Else statement with the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in your code behind.

Comment: I did that because it throws an error if you try to access an object in the loggedintemplate while it is displaying the anonymoustemplate. This code is in the Page_Load event method by the way.

Comment: nvm, the code I had works visual studio messed up the connection to my db somehow. thanks for the reply